# Whenever I plug in HDMI, my laptop believes that VGA was also connected

Tags: laptop, display

I have an ASUS laptop, N55SF, the nice black one with a NVIDIA GT 555M.

Whenever I plug in HDMI my computer reacts as if VGA has been connected, thus giving me 3 screens.

Both Windows and the NVIDIA control panel shows it as being connected and I can disable VGA in the NVIDIA control panel, but that's a workaround at best, I do use VGA from time to time.

Having looked through the NVIDIA control panel and Windows equivalents I can't help but wonder, what have I missed?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Do you have the latest BIOS, Windows Updates and NVidia software & drivers?

Comment: THank you! Yes, I have the latest (non-beta) drivers, but I have the same problem with beta NVidia drivers.